How to add line breaks to markdown text in SwiftUI
I'm having trouble adding line breaks in markdown in Swift when I create the markdown text using an AttributedString. The first example works but the second is not working for me.
struct MarkdownText: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I am **bold**.\nI am *italic*.")
            Text(try! AttributedString(markdown: "I am **bold**.\nI am *italic*."))
        }
    }
}


If clarification is needed I'm generating my markdown dynamically which requires using AttributedString.

How do you normally add a line break using Stack Overflow's answer editor? Just adding one new line character isn't enough, is it?

This is for Swift code. Is my post not clear on that?

@Sweeper is saying that, with Mark Down generally, a single line break in your "source" is not enough to generate a line break in the output. You need to put a <br/> tag in.

I'm not sure how to make this post more clear. This is not for HTML. This is for Markdown in Swift.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-markdown-content-in-text

"A  \nB" (two spaces after A)

You need to use the options property with .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace. Try this:
Text(try! AttributedString(markdown: "I am **bold**.\nI am *italic*.", 
                           options: .init(interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace))) //<- here


this breaks block styles like unordered lists headings etc
